# How to intercept a Javascript/CSS file request from the Webpage at the cleint side, and load alternative files insted?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

For example, a webpage loads its JavaScript files like this inside the head tag:

```
<script src="http://www.somedomain.com/js/somejsfile.js"></script>
```

or for CSS files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
      href="http://www.somedomain.com/somecssfile.css">
```

What I want to achieve is that, while loading the page itself, instead of the original `http://www.somedomain.com/js/somejsfile.js` it should load another file `http://www.anotherdomain.com/js/anotherfile.js`

May be via some custom firefox/chrome (preferably not IE) extension or something else.

Hint:

> This can be also used to subsitute jQuery library etc. to load from local source instead of remote Google* hosted file.

Comment: This is for your own local use I assume? I'd recommend looking up Greasemonkey and writing a script for it.https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/

Comment: @KingCronus: GreaseMonkey isn't the answer to all questions. It won't work here, GreaseMonkey will only become active after the script loads.

Comment: Valid point, i'd not thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

injecting your own content script at "document_start" will give you the chance to analise and modify the document, even before the DOM is constructed and any script is started.
But at that time, all CSS files are already loaded.  Perhaps you may redefine them with other CSS.

See "run_at" property in "content-scripts" property, in manifest.json:
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html

Comment: This approche doesn't work.
As you said, `document_start` works "before the DOM is constructed", so, you can not "analyse and modify the document" as you will not find neither  `head` nor `body` to analyse.